# Why are two descriptions of strong zero-dimensionality equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, compactification, zero-dimensionality

**Def:** A Tychonoff space $X$ is said to be strongly zero-dimensional if
its Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ is totally disconnected (that is if the only
connected subspaces of $\beta X$ are singletons).

I have heard that strong zero-dimensionality of $X$ provides that disjoint zero-sets are separated by clopen sets. My question is: why is this equivalent? Could you provide a source for proof or anything?

Thank you.

(By $\beta X$, we mean the Stone-Čech compactification of $X$).

Comment: Engelking, General topology 6.2.4, 6.2.12 and 6.2.10.

Comment: @Ulli Wouldn´t the theorem 6.2.4 be enough? Or maybe I just dont see how these three theorems put together to obtain the result in my question.

Comment: No, you need the others as well: 6.2.12 and 6.2.10 to show that your definition of strong zero-dimensionality is the same as Engelking's.

Comment: @Ulli I am sorry, I still cant see it. Engelking defines strong zero-dimensionality via open refinements, which is something different than the two equivalent definitions I have written. Hence, I dont understand, how 6.2.10 and 6.2.12 imply that my two definitions are equivalent? I dont even see how it leads to Theorem 6.2.4.

Comment: Ok, step by step: All spaces are Tychonoff.
Let's say $X$ is *szd*, if $\beta X$ is totally disconnected, i.e. exactly your definition.
$X$ is called *E-szd*, if it is strongly zero-dimensional as defined in Engelking's book.
Then by 6.2.10: $X$ szd $\Leftrightarrow$ $\beta X$ totally disonnected $\Leftrightarrow$ $\beta X$ E-szd. By 6.2.12: $\beta X$ E-szd $\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ E-szd. Hence $X$ szd $\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ E-szd.

Comment: 6.2.4: $X$ E-szd $\Leftrightarrow$ every $A, B$ completely separated subsets of $X$ can be separated by clopen subsets, which is obviously equivalent to "*disjoint zero-sets are separated by clopen sets*", i.e. exactly the condition you are asking for.